# Read json file and get output values

Tags: python, json, ioerror

I want to fetch the output of below json file using python

Json file

```json
{
    "Name": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "Avg": "55.7"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rose",
            "Avg": "71.23"
        },
        {
            "name": "Lola",
            "Avg": "78.93"
        },
        {
            "name": "Harry",
            "Avg": "95.5"
        }

    ]
}
```

I want to get the average marks of the person, when I look for harry
i.e. I need output in below or similar format

`Harry = 95.5`

Here's my code

```
import json

json_file = open('test.json')  //the above contents are stored in the json
data = json.load(json_file)
do = data['Name'][0]
op1 = do['Name']
if op1 is 'Harry':
    print do['Avg']
```

But when I run I get error `IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long`.

Comment: where is the json coming from? what have you tried

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, nobody is here to write all the code for you. If you can edit to show what you tried and what didn't work, we can help you with that. There's plenty of questions and answers on handling JSON in Python already.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete info, i am new to this forum, here's my code

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i had did a workaround by converting the contents into dict type and got the output in desired format

Answer (score 1):

How to print the score of Harry with python 3

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('test.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for l in data["Name"]:
    if (str(l['name']) == 'Harry'):
        pprint(l['Avg'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple like this

```
import json

file = open('data.json')
json_data = json.load(file)

stud_list = json_data['Name']
y = {}
for var in stud_list:
    x = {var['name']: var['Avg']}
    y = dict(list(x.items()) + list(y.items()))

print(y)
```

It gives the output in dictionary format

```js
{'Harry': '95.5', 'Lola': '78.93', 'Rose': '71.23', 'John': '55.7'}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) loads data from file `file-like` object. If you want to read it from string you may use `json.loads`.